# Preferred DB Connection for ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, database

What's the preferred (best practice) means of connecting an ASP.Net Website to a database?  I doubt it's as simple as using Trusted-Connection and giving the NT-Authority accounts access.

What do y'all do?  Assuming a clean install of SQL Server (2008), what do you do to configure access to the database for a website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually run ASP.NET app pool as a separate account (not `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE`) and use Windows authentication to access the SQL Server. This method has the advantage of not storing the password in config files.

Steps:

1. Create a user account to run your ASP.NET application on.
2. Create an application pool in IIS and run it on the created account.
3. Assign NTFS permissions that your application needs to the account.
4. Grant permission to login on SQL Server.
5. Assign the appropriate database roles to the created login.

This will work for many apps. For more complex security environments, you might need more sophisticated strategies.

Comment: That makes sense.  Can you provide a link or maybe more instruction regarding implementation?

Comment: Also bear in mind that you can define your own roles for a database - if you're trying for best practice you want to limit what an application (the associated user) can or can't do beyond the inherent restrictions in the standard roles.

Answer (score 0):

I used to use trusted connections, but ended up feeling that that sometimes I ended up having to grant too many privileges to the service account used for the connection/app pool.  Now I use SQL Server accounts and set up the application to encrypt the connection strings during Application_Start if they aren't already encrypted.  In fact I encrypt any section that may contain user credentials.  I use an appSetting to determine whether the encryption code runs so I don't encrypt my settings in the development environment.

Comment: For large apps that might have different permissions, I completely agree. (SQL Server application role is an another way to achieve least privileges). But many Web apps are small enough that it doesn't make sense to have many different accounts. Passwords will create maintenance issues...

Answer (score 0):

I also use SQL Server accounts, just find it simpler to do and to troubleshoot.